# EF6 triggers new query on "Include"?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6 and I noticed that when I "include" a child table in a query, EF triggers a new query for each one of the parent rows...is that ok? is there a way to avoid it and make it bring all the information with the main query only?

Here are my entities (not the exact code):

```
public class Contractor
{
   public int id { get; set;}
   public IEnumerable<ContractorEmployee> Employees;
}

public class ContractorEmployee
{
   public int id { get; set;}
   public int contractorId { get; set;}
}
```

And this is the query:

```
var fullContractors = dbContext.Contractors.Include("ContractorEmployee");
```

so if the fullContractors query retrieves 5 contractors, I see 5 extra queries in SQL bringing the contractor employees of each one of them.

Any way to avoid this and bring it all in the first "SELECT"???

Comment: How do you know that it triggers 5 extra queries?

Comment: Show us how fullContractors is being used later in your code.

Comment: After some time checking this problem I realized it was an error in my code, sorry guys, please delete this post and I totally get it if you down vote me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it was an error in the code I am working on, not EF6's, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`Include` method takes the name of the parameter as string it is recommended to use overloaded version of Include that takes `Expression` as parameter.
You can have look at the overloaded version of extension method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx).

So do it Either

```
var fullContractors = dbContext.Contractors.Include("Employees");
```

or go with `Expression` version like this:

```
var fullContractors = dbContext.Contractors.Include(d => d.Employees);
```